# Importing LokiJS on Ionic2 Typescript app

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings, lokijs

I'm new to TypeScript and Ionic2 and tried to use LokiJS on a first app.

So far I created a new app as suggested on Ionic2 doc:

```
npm install -g ionic cordova typings
ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2
cd cutePuppyPics
```

After that I installed loki and used typings to integrate it:

```
npm install lokijs
typings install dt~lokijs --global --save
```

Then I edited one of the given pages of the tab panel: *pages/home/home.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as lokijs from "lokijs";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    if(!!lokijs)
      console.log("loki there");
      else console.log("no loki :(");
  }
}
```

Bundling app works fine, but on the console I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined(…)

Is this a error on the typings definition?

What am I missing? How to properly import lokijs to Ionic2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386734/how-to-use-lokijs-cordova-fs-adapter-in-ionic-2
this might help you